# Regular Expressions : What is wrong with grep "[a-z]{2}" somename.txt

Tags: regex, bash, unix

I am a beginner at UNIX and using bash shell. I have created a file containing some Common names to understand the working of the grep regular expressions. The problem is that there is no output shown even though the files contains the relevant text. If I type as `[a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z]`, it works just fine. Pls help. What changes will I have to make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regular expression syntax `grep` uses, you have to backslash the curlies to turn on their special meaning:

```
grep '[a-z]\{2\}'
```

Or, turn on the "extended" regular expressions (`-E`) to make it work without backslashing:

```
grep -E '[a-z]{2}'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @choroba.